# How to write a WHERE clause with row_number in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, where-clause, ssms, row-number

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY opened_at) RN
    FROM 
        table
)
SELECT column1, column2
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 2
```

If there is no `RN = 2`, how I can return `RN = 1` instead?

If I code something like

```
WHERE RN = IIF (RN = 2,2,1)
```

it will return both `RN = 1` and `RN = 2` for the rows that have 1 and 2. I only need `RN = 2`, or `RN = 1`, if `RN = 2` does not exist.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Try change ordering by  ``OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY opened_at DESC) RN``  and then ``WHERE RN=1``. In case where rn maybe in(1,2) or (1) this helps.

Comment: can you show some sample data with expected result?

Comment: Are there always one or two rows or do you want row `2` returned in the case that there are two _or more_ rows?

Comment: @HABO yes, there are almost always more than 2 rows for the same ID, so I need to return row 2 in such scenario, but if there is one row only, then I need to return row 1. ValNik shared a great idea below to use not only row_number function, but also count (*). I think it should give me what I need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count rows in partition by Id. If there 1 row (count=1) then rn=1 - nothing to do. If count>1 then take RN=2.
Try this

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY opened_at) RN
  , count (*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) qty
FROM table)

SELECT column1, column2
FROM CTE
WHERE (qty>1 and RN = 2) or (qty=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by getting max rn per id where the the max rn <= 2 then apply a join to get the expected output :

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY opened_at) RN
FROM mytable
)
SELECT c.*
FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, max(rn) as max_rn
  FROM CTE
  where rn <= 2
  GROUP BY id
) as s on s.id = c.id and s.max_rn = c.rn
```